# How to connect to a UDP daemon running in a port

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, port

I am hardly trying to connect my client application to a daemon who is running in another computer.

Those are the settings:

Server side:

```
ip: 10.0.0.1
gateway: 10.0.0.2
```

client side:

```
ip: 10.0.0.2
gateway: 10.0.0.2
```

---

Those are the ports the daemon uses:

```
Server  address: 0.0.0.0:1235
Client  address: 127.0.0.1:1236
Service ID     : 53
```

The daemon is suppose to be expection a client in

> ip address 10.0.0.2 port 1241.

I am opening a UDP socket on that port, but I dont receive any traffic.

Sorry if I am doing something wrong but I am new in networks!

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check that there is a process listening the correct UDP port(s) on your server with command `netstat -ul`. After that try connecting to the server UDP port from client machine with netcat, using command `netcat -u <server address> <server port>`, while also listening the traffic on server side with tcpdump, using command `tcpdump -i <interface your server is listening to> host <client ip address>`.

That should produce some tangible output in form of UDP packets when you type something on terminal where you've ran netcat. And in case tcpdump shows nothing, you can see that there is a connectivity problem instead of problem with your UDP server.

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot!! Can I vote your answer or something?